# cannot load such file -- paypal/express on db migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have installed the paypal express gem and after trying to do migrations I receive a `cannot load such file -- paypal/express` error.

Log:

```
$ gem install paypal-express
Successfully installed paypal-express-0.5.5
Parsing documentation for paypal-express-0.5.5
1 gem installed
$ rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- paypal/express
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
/dating/config/initializers/paypal.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in `load'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in `block in load'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in `load'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/engine.rb:609:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/engine.rb:608:in `each'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/engine.rb:608:in `block in <class:Engine>'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/application.rb:214:in `initialize!'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/dating/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/application.rb:188:in `require_environment!'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/application.rb:248:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
```

Comment: Are you using Bundler? Why not put that gem in the Gemfile and install it with bundle install. Rake will run Bundler.setup and make sure the gems are available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `gem 'paypal-express'` in your Gemfile and run `bundle install`. You shouldn't even have to require `paypal/express` in your initializer.

Comment: Thanks. I also needed to create the model from the terminal so I can run my migration.

Comment: @pwz2000 Can you please tell how did you solve this? I know its pretty long time. But still in case if you can remember. I am badly stuck on this error.