# Ruby on Rails: LoadError: cannot load such file -- paypal-express

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

When I do

```
rake db:migrate
```

It simply fails. Here is log:

```
$ rake db:migrate
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/duplicable.rb:82: warning: BigDecimal.new is deprecated; use BigDecimal() method instead.
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:282: warning: circular argument reference - now
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated
rake aborted!
SystemStackError: stack level too deep
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rest-client-2.0.2/lib/restclient/version.rb:3:in `map'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rest-client-2.0.2/lib/restclient/version.rb:3:in `<module:RestClient>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rest-client-2.0.2/lib/restclient/version.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rest-client-2.0.2/lib/restclient.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rest-client-2.0.2/lib/rest_client.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/paypal-express-0.8.1/lib/paypal.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/paypal-express-0.8.1/lib/paypal/express.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:95:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:95:in `rescue in block in require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/myproject/RubyOnRails/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/myproject/RubyOnRails/Rakefile:4:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/myproject/RubyOnRails/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'

Caused by:
LoadError: cannot load such file -- paypal-express
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/myproject/RubyOnRails/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/myproject/RubyOnRails/Rakefile:4:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/myproject/RubyOnRails/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I tried suggestions given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21053281/cannot-load-such-file-paypal-express-on-db-migrate) answer:

1. I am already having gem 'paypal-express' in my Gemfile
2. I manually installed `paypal-express` gem:

   gem install paypal-express

Still no luck. Questioner of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21053281/cannot-load-such-file-paypal-express-on-db-migrate) given clue that:

> I needed to create the model from the terminal so I can run my migration

But I do not know how to do that (if I want to try it).
Any help would be really appreciated. **I am new to RoR.**

Comment: You shouldn't need to run `gem install paypal-express`. That installs the gem globally on your system; but this project is using a **restricted** set of gems, defined in the `Gemfile`. Instead, as with all other ruby dependencies in the project, you need to install them as part of the **bundle**. Run: `bundle install`.

Comment: @TomLord I already did `bundle install` but no luck

Comment: Do you still get the same error when running `bundle exec rake db:migrate`, instead of just `rake db:migrate`?

Comment: @TomLord: I just given try, yes I do get exact same error

Comment: Are you able to post a [mcve] to reproduce the problem? E.g. a `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock`, which I can use on my machine to reproduce the above error?

Comment: @TomLord I got it resolved when I tried multiple things :)I believe it is something with what I did with database solved this. But I will post answer after I complete my analysis what exactly solved this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized root cause of this problem was because I had forgotten to import DB (In other words, my DB was empty). I know it's silly mistake still I am posting it here in case it could help someone coming here in future. I imported DB by doing this:

```
sudo mysql -u root -p <db name> < /home/ubuntu/my_site_data.sql
```